# While making pdf from HTML code how to hide the elements having style "display:none"?

Tags: itext

I am getting the response from a URL and trying to create pdf from the response.
I am using iTextSharp.
The HTML of the URL has some images which have styles defined as
style="display:none". In the pdf these images are visible. How to make them invisible.

I have tried with replacing  "display:none" with  "visibility:hidden". But this did not work.

Can anyone please tell how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `width` and `height` to `0px`

You can use CSS media types to do this for print only

```
@media print {
   /* styles for printing */
}
```

Comment: If it solves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted. It will benefit the community (and my points)

Comment: Sadly this is not working for `tables` or `paragraphs`. Any other options?

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt why would it not work on tables and paragraphs? (I assume you mean the `<table>` and `<p>` tags)